# escaping an ampersand in xsl variable

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to encode certain text variables into a QR code using qrserver.com. (specifically, a gift message on a packing slip)
Here's the snippet of code relevant to the encoding:

```
<!-- gift message -->
                   <xsl:for-each select="Customer/Order/Item">
                             <xsl:for-each select="Option[Name='Gift Message (optional)']">

                        <xsl:variable name="test" select="translate(Description,'','')" />
                             <xsl:value-of select="concat('https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=', $test,'&amp;size=100x100&amp;charset-source=UTF-8')" />
                             </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

Occasionally the text will contain an ampersand, like "Merry Christmas & Happy New Year", so the url that is passed is

https://api.qrserver.c-o-m/v1/create-qr-code/?data=Merry Christmas & Happy New Year&size=100x100

and everything after the ampersand gets truncated. The result is a QR code that encodes "Merry Christmas" but no Happy New Year. I tried using the translate function to replace the ampersand with "and", but translate(Description,'&','and') only works on the first letter, so it replaces the ampersand with "a". This is in xsl 1.0, so I don't have the option of the replace function. Does anyone out there know how I can deal with these ampersands? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know xlst-1.0, but translate is typically a character function, you should be using a string replacement function instead.

Comment: Fiddler - &amp would probably work if there was some way to get it into the url. When the xsl document generates the url, it includes the gift message exactly as it exists in the database. It doesn't url encode it, so if there's an ampersand in the message, there's an ampersand in the url.

Comment: Adam - You may be right, but I'll admit I don't really know what that means. I'm not a coder by any means - I can fiddle around with existing code to make tweaks and can usually get it to do what I want, but my vast knowledge ends there. The fact that your comment was a bit over my head pretty well sums up my expertise. Is this something that can be done short and simply, or is it "more complicated than that"?